# Is there (anymore) a keybinding for creating a new folder in the GTK3 File chooser?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, gtk3

In GTK 2, it's possible to create a new folder via shortcut `Ctrl+Shift+N`. In GTK 3, the shortcut doesn't trigger any behavior.

I've checked the [API page](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooserWidget.html), but I can't find the event.

Did the GNOME team remove the binding, or they changed it to something else?

Comment: are you trying that on empty desktop? have you tried it when Files app is open?

Comment: on an empty desktop, the shortcut works, however, that's not a File Chooser dialog.

Comment: Oh, OK.. I got your point.. sorry I did not get that one while writing above comment..

Comment: It seems this is not available in a GTK3 dialog indeed, unfortunatelly

Comment: Same discussion here: https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/d43cgm/shortcut_to_create_a_new_folder_in_the_save_dialog/

Answer (score 1):

As of August/2020, the functionality is missing; it got lost in the transition from GTK2 to GTK3.

Tracking issue: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/957.